# lsp-mode: How to use built-in clangd client?

Tags: init-file, completion, c++

I'm trying to use `lsp-mode` (together with `company-lsp`) for auto completion in C++. According to the docs[0], recent `lsp-mode` includes clangd support, so I should be all set when I do `(require 'lsp-clients)`. However, `lsp-mode` can't find any clients to handle `c++-mode`, and from the documentation I can't find any way of debugging this.

## The Main Problem

Here is the (almost) complete `init.el` file, which I have produced as a minimal example:

```
(unless (package-installed-p 'lsp-mode)
  (package-install 'lsp-mode))
(unless (package-installed-p 'company-lsp)
  (package-install 'company-lsp))
(unless (package-installed-p 'lsp-ui)
  (package-install 'lsp-ui))

(require 'company-lsp)
(require 'lsp-mode)
(require 'lsp-ui)
(require 'lsp-clients)

(push 'company-lsp company-backends)
(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'global-company-mode)

(add-hook 'lsp-mode-hook 'lsp-ui-mode)

(when (string= (system-name) "i11pcbarth")
    (setq lsp-clients-clangd-executable "/usr/lib/llvm-7/bin/clangd"))

(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'lsp)
```

Now, when I open a C++ file, I get the message

> Unable to find client(s) handling c++-mode. Make sure you have
>   required lsp-clients.el or proper extension.

Since I already do `(require 'lsp-clients)` above, I'm not sure what to do.

## Further Weirdness

Looking into `lsp-clients.el`, I can see that it should define e.g. the variable `lsp-clients-clangd-executable`. However, the variable seems not to be defined (I can't find it using `C-h v`). So, I assume that for some reason, the `(require 'lsp-clients)` from my `init.el` did not work. Thus, I require the file again (by typing `(require 'lsp-clients)` into the current buffer and calling `eval-last-sexp`). Now, `C-h v` sees the variable `lsp-clients-clangd-executable`. However, `M-x lsp RET` (to enable `lsp-mode`) again only gives me the error message about no client that handles `c++-mode`.

[0] https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-clangd/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**EDIT:** As of late December 2018, this is no longer required, and lsp-mode does the required setup automatically. It was fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/commit/7803af23cc4c479ea1ce28b10122a2052a6edc65) as far as I can tell.

You need to call `lsp-clients-register-clangd`, as per https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-clangd/issues/11. To do this, you can either call it interactively using `M-x lsp-clients-register-clangd` to enable it in your current emacs session, or call it from your `init.el` after requiring `lsp` and `lsp-clients`. The result should look something like this:

```
(require 'lsp)
(require 'lsp-clients)
(lsp-clients-register-clangd)
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'lsp)
```

According to https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/issues/537, this is a temporary issue, and calling `lsp-clients-register-clangd` should not be necessary in the future.

Comment: Welcome!  For the sake of completeness, could you please update your answer to be explicit about what code needs to be added?

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean, Dan. No code is missing from lsp-mode, but its documentation is sparse. You only need to call `lsp-clients-register-clangd` either manually via `M-x lsp-clients-register-clangd` or put `(lsp-clients-register-clangd)` in your init.el after requiring lsp-mode.

Comment: Please edit your post to explain exactly that.  The idea is to make sure someone who sees this post somewhere down the line will be able to figure out exactly what you did to resolve the problem.

Comment: Ah, right! I updated it with a full config example that should be sufficient to get it working.